# Contact Form 7 not sending email with custom url structure

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have some pages where I query some data from the database. Those pages have a little bit different URL as custom on WP; they all end with ?id=12345. (For example: https://example.com/page?id=12345) 
Contact Form 7 is working flawlessly on every page except for those pages where the url structure ends like this ?id=12345. When I press "send message", it alerts me that message was sent. In reality it wasn't.

What's causing it and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

the issue with SMTP please use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/) plugin 
or
check email in the spam folder.
or
Try to edit form make sure there are no errors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Did you consider that CF7 is working just fine on my site on normal pages and I have this issue only on pages with custom url structure?

Comment: How are your permalinks set?

Comment: Like normal https://example.com/example/example/ except for queried pages where structure looks like this: https://example.com/example/example/?id=12345 Only on those pages CF7 isn't working. I'm guessing because of different url structure